# css responsive square with overflow

Tags: html, css

i have a responsive square with text inside. i want the square to keep his proportions on all sizes, unless the text inside is overflow, than i want the square to be taller. 
now, the text is just hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/38Tnx/2253/

```
<div class='square-box'>
   <div class='square-content'>
      <div>
         <span>text</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
}
.square-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
.square-content div {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.square-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your **`.square-box`** css with the following code

```
.square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/38Tnx/2255/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```css
.square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    /*background: #4679BD;*/
}
.square-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
.square-content div {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
    background:#4679BD; /* moved */
}
.square-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works fine if there are no any other divs around it. but see what happens if there is a new div after - http://jsfiddle.net/38Tnx/2258/

Comment: What is the expected behaviour here? The div with the class 'square-content' has absolute positioning hence why the new div is sitting underneath.

Comment: the next div should show at the end of the first one so i guess i need a different solution for responsive square div